# React State reverting to default value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update a Component from inside a nested component. But each time the state in the parent component gets reset to it's initial value.
Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

The initial data:

```
    {
        id: 1,
        size: "large",
        name: "Antman",
        url: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91lviq1Lx6L._AC_UL320_SR320,320_.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        size: "large",
        name: "Avatar",
        url: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91XXks9tlfL._AC_UL320_SR320,320_.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        size: "large",
        name: "Shazam",
        url: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91mXAXL+jBL._AC_UL320_SR320,320_.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        size: "large",
        name: "Test",
        url: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91mXAXL+jBL._AC_UL320_SR320,320_.jpg"
    }
];
```

Parent Component

```
function DragDrop() {
    const [blockList, setBlocklist] = useState(initblockList);

    const updateBlockList = (block, id) => {
        const update = blockList.filter(block => block.id !== id); //block list reverts to initState
        setBlocklist((update) => [...update]); //remove block from blocklist state
    }

    return (
        <>
            <AboveBoard
                blockList={blockList}
                setAbove={setAboveBoard}
                updateBlockList={updateBlockList}
            />
            <div className="blocks">
                {blockList.map((img, i) => {
                    return <Block key={`key-${i}`} id={img.id} url={img.url} />
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default DragDrop
```

Child Component

```
function AboveBoard({ blockList, setAbove, updateBlockList }) {
    const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);

    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "block",
        drop: (item) => addBlockToBoard(item.id),
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }))
    const addBlockToBoard = (id) => {
        const currentBlock = blockList.filter(block => block.id === id);
        setBoard((board) => [...board, currentBlock[0]]); //add new block to board
        updateBlockList(currentBlock, id); //update parent board
    }

    return (
        <div className="aboveboard" ref={drop}>
            {board.map((img, i) => {
                return <UnBlock key={`key-${i}`} id={img.id} url={img.url} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AboveBoard
```

This code is using React DND but the main issue is the blocklist state.
When I drag a card from blocks div it should update the blocklist state on the parent and remove it from the block list. Next update should filter through the updated state but the blocklist always reverts back to initial value when this line runs
`const update = blockList.filter(block => block.id !== id);`

Not sure why the state is being reset.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should be `setBlocklist(update)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, because in the `setBlocklist` state setter where you're using the setter form, you're using the same name for the old state as well as the new(filtered) list as an update value.

Edit: Looking through your code & comments, I noticed that you're trying to pass the variable `currentBlock` to the `updateBlockList` state setter. Problem is, it's returned from the filter method as an array by default & so, it will be passed down as an array, thus the state will never be updated because the `.id` property doesn't exist on the `block` variable inside the filter method of the `updateBlockList`.

Solution would be using the `.find` method in the `addBlockToBoard` method or accessing the first index, i.e., `currentBlock[0]`.

Edit: After taking a look at the code sandbox, the issue was the old state value being stale(stale closures), thus, the state was reset each time a change happened. In this case, we can only use the setter form of `setState(prevState => ...);`. [Recommended reading about stale closures issue](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

Here is the updated code:

The parent component:

```js
function DragDrop() {
    const [blockList, setBlocklist] = useState(initblockList);

    const updateBlockList = (currentBlock, id) => {
        setBlocklist((prevState) => prevState.filter(block => block.id !== currentBlock.id));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <AboveBoard
                blockList={blockList}
                setAbove={setAboveBoard}
                updateBlockList={updateBlockList}
            />
            <div className="blocks">
                {blockList.map((img, i) => {
                    return <Block key={`key-${i}`} id={img.id} url={img.url} />
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default DragDrop
```

The child component:

```js
function AboveBoard({ blockList, setAbove, updateBlockList }) {
    const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);

    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "block",
        drop: (item) => addBlockToBoard(item.id),
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }))
    const addBlockToBoard = (id) => {
        const currentBlock = blockList.find(block => block.id === id);
        // OR
       // const currentBlock = blockList.filter(block => block.id === id)[0];
        setBoard((board) => [...board, currentBlock]); //add new block to board
        updateBlockList(currentBlock); //update parent board
    }

    return (
        <div className="aboveboard" ref={drop}>
            {board.map((img, i) => {
                return <UnBlock key={`key-${i}`} id={img.id} url={img.url} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the spread syntax for setBlocklist(filteredList) since Array.filter returns a new array, but otherwise it appears to be the right answer.

Comment: @elunomas, I agree. Edited the post.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli Thanks for your answer. Looking at the solution the first one just changes the variable name. I also tried the 2nd solution passing prevState but this didn't solve my problem either. The state still defaults back to 4 items when I update it after the first time. Also, I agree the spread operator is redundant.

Comment: Every time this function runs:

const updateBlockList = (block, id) => {
        console.log("Right before filter: ", blockList);
        const filteredList = blockList.filter(b => b.id !== id);
        setBlocklist(filteredList);
    }

The blockList state is set back to initial value.

Comment: @CraigBauer, That's strange, are you sure you have included all the code above. If possible, create a minimal example [here](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli thanks for taking a look. I moved the whole thing to a codepen. It's behaving the same way as my local install. I have a feeling react DND may have something to do with this so I included that code too.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-napier-ipyg86?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @CraigBauer - I have solved the issue. You will find the solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-robinson-lomxdr). It was a stale closure issue. I have edited the above answer to reflect the changes made :)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli Thank you again for looking at this. That definitely got rid of the weird issues I was having but the item is still not being removed from the blocklist after it is dragged to one of the boards.
I would like update block list to update the state with the dragged item removed so it can't be dragged again. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CraigBauer - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253849/discussion-between-abdulrahman-ali-and-craig-bauer).

Comment: The above code fixed the issue but this line should be
const currentBlock = blockList.find(block => block[0].id === id);
Because block is an array with 1 object inside.

Comment: @CraigBauer - Oh, okay. But in your post, the original `blockList` is shown as an array of objects.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli my bad. That is not needed when using .find()